# Where can I find more documentation on building an Ubuntu-based cloud infrastructure?

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

I've been reading: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

It's fascinating stuff, but documentation seems a bit sparse. Where I work, we have this aging, clunky VMWare ESXi setup for all our internal servers. I'd really like to read up on possible migration or just information on Orchestra, integration with Juju, etc that isn't a bunch of loosely connected blog posts. :p

This is concerning 11.10 and, presumably, 12.04.

To make this less vague, specifically documentation on:

- Orchestra - features, comparisons, videos, etc
- Integrating Juju with Orchestra - I'm familiar with using Juju for deploying on AWS, but that wiki page glances over connecting it to orchestra
- Building a private cloud - Advantages, using/deploying Openstack, etc
- Working with internal networks - Configuring DMZs, setting rules, etc

Any recommended books would be appreciated too. I didn't intend for this to be a 'do all my homework for me! LMGTFY' post, I'm just hungry for information and haven't found a good repository of knowledge for much of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I'm in the process of doing what you are talking about right now.
I have a small cluster at home that I am learning to deploy these technologies on.

All of these tools are changing VERY RAPIDLY in my opinion.

Two months ago, I started learning Orchestra. Last week I was posting here, and found out that Orchestra has been deprecated. Now MaaS on 12.04 is the way to go, and so far it has been just as rococo as Orchestra was.

Its hard to find documentation from people that are doing it. That is why I am posting alot of questions here.

I did find the MaaS wiki pages, which are helpful: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS

Maybe this helps you get started.